# PHP: Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_pkcs12_read()

Tags: php, openssl, sles

I'm using PHP to read encryted file using opensll.

when doing

```
openssl_pkcs12_read($storedfile, $certificateinfo, $passwd)
```

in my script, error came out is :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function openssl_pkcs12_read()

I'm trying to install `openssl` `extension` for my Suse Linux Enterprise Server 11.

Can anybody help me how to install `openssl extension` in SLES. or how to solve this problem.

thanks

Comment: search for installing openssl in suse distribution. You can find a lot of usefull guides

Comment: I'm not understanding if the issue is related to the function's calling itself or the module's installation.

Besides the last one, have you included the file related to that function in the PHP file where you'll use the function itself?